# JQuery form validation I need a click event in knockoutjs to validate form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a save button HTML and inside a form with id myform

```
   <button data-bind="click: save" type="submit">Save</button>
```

I am validating the form using jquery validator as below..

```
   $("#myform").validate({ submitHandler: myVM.save });
```

in my knockout view model I have a function that is save and sends my ajax post data to server.

I want to validate the form before send the data to server, but it does not as it is an event I believe.

my save function inside myVM is something like below...

```
   self.save = function(){  $.ajax({ My ajax post info }) }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer:

I just added:

```
           if (!$("#myform").valid())
                alert("form not valid");
```

before my ajax call and it worked.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing your own AJAX call to send the data to the server, then change the button's type to be "button", not "submit", so the browser don't try to submit the whole form to the browser.

Comment: I actually do want the whole form to be validated all the elements within form are like so: <td><input class='required' data-bind='value:Name, uniqueName: true' /></td>

Comment: I'm not questioning validating the form, but your last code block suggests the sending of the data back to the server is via AJAX call. My point is you're going to be sending the data twice, once in the AJAX call and once via browser submitting the form.